# How to parse Text file c# and get correct result data

Tags: c#, parsing

I am parsing a text file to get settings data for Bluetooth:

This value could be disabled or enabled and marked with an *.

The problem I am having is that its always returning status as "Enabled" regardless if its disabled or not.

Could this be due to that text its reading from has a tab in front of the lines that are indented.
How can I correct this to work?

```
  private String GetBluetoothStatus(String FilePath)
{
    String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
    int index = 0;
    string status = "";
    foreach (String s in lines)
    {
        if (s == "Bluetooth")
        {
            if (lines[index + 1].StartsWith("*"))
                status = "Disabled";
            else
                status = "Enabled";
            return status;
        }
        index += 1;
    }
    return status;
}
```

The text file is below:

```
BIOSConfig 1.0
;
;     Originally created by BIOS Configuration Utility
;     Version: 4.0.25.1
;     Date="2018/08/06" Time="15:42:35" UTC="-5"
;
;     Found 182 settings
;
Power On When AC Detected
    *Disabled
    Enabled
Power On When Lid is Opened
    *Disabled
    Enabled
Fast Boot
    *Disable
    Enable
Bluetooth
    Disabled
    *Enabled
Wireless Network Device (WLAN)
    Disabled
    *Enabled
LAN / WLAN Auto Switching
    Disabled
    *Enabled
```

Comment: Suggestion. If you want to track of index, then use `for` not `foreach` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change following line

```
if (lines[index + 1].StartsWith("*"))
```

to

```
  if (lines[index + 1].Trim().StartsWith("*Disabled"))
```

Better use `Contains` like follwoing as you have mentioned that `Enable` `Disable` can appear in same line also.

```
if (lines[index + 1].Contains("*Disabled"))
```

Comment: if the text reads :

Bluetooth

    *Disabled

    Enabled


will the same line work?  the setting could be either way and I need it to read the one marked currently with * when the text file is generated?

Answer (score 1):

You do `lines[index + 1].StartsWith("*")` but if we look your config file it begin with space/tabulation.

Try to test `lines[index + 1].Trim().StartsWith("*")` to remove this blank space/tabulation before check the value.

If trim don't work, try `lines[index + 1].Replace("\t", " ").Replace(" ","").StartsWith("*");`